# Try cant catch exception in tkinter

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet:

```
def start_server():
    try:
        global ucs2
        ucs2 = socket.socket()
        ucs2.connect(server_add)
    except Exception:
        textfield.config(state=NORMAL)
        textfield.insert(END, str(geterror())+"\n")
        textfield.config(state=DISABLED)

    else:
        textfield.config(state=NORMAL)
        textfield.insert(END, "Success!\n")
        textfield.config(state=DISABLED)
        listen()
        thread.start_new_thread(new_msg, ())
if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    add_widget()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", warnexit)



    root.after(3000, start_server)

    root.mainloop()
```

However, if I run this, even if the `ucs2` socket raises an Exception like `ConnectionRefusedError`, it will just display the error on the console and wouldn't catch it. What problem is this?

Comment: if you are still not able to catch it, that might be an unhandled exception in any library functions. They may not be throwing it to the calling function. I am not a python expert. Just sharing a thought.

Comment: just curious, shouldn't you use `finally` on `listen() ...` and place `textfield...` inside `try` block?

Comment: @ Anzel Nope. listen() is related to sockets, so if the ucs2 socket cant connect, it cant run listen.

Comment: Please post a self-contained example that *we can run* to duplicate your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't catch `ConnectionRefusedError`. Do this:

```
except ConnectionRefusedError:
```

Comment: `ConnectionRefusedError` is a descendent of `Exception`, so `except Exception` *should* catch it, if it is raised in the associated `try` block.

Comment: @ chepner there was a indent error. Fixed by adding that block.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the exception is actually being thrown from within the try-catch block. If it is, you can use the following syntax to catch all exceptions:

```
try:
    do_stuff()
except: #Catches Everything (This is usually a bad idea)
    catch_stuff()
```